# Listing file names present in a directory without using import os

Tags: python, file, directory, subdirectory

I am attempting to create a program allowing new user creation on python. However already created users get overwritten if the name of the new profile is the same as the old one, this is because a new text file is created with the selected username as the title, so the new text file replaces the old one.

Due to restrictions on my system I am unable to use `import os`, so I need an alternative method to list all the file names present in a directory or subdirectory, so they can be compared to the new username and cancel the user creation if a file with that name already exists to prevent users being overwritten.

Snippet of my code:

```
new_username=str(input('Please choose a username : '))
new_password=str(input('Please choose a password : '))
print("Good Choice!")

title=new_username + '.txt'           #Creating title of the file
file=open(title,'w')                  #Creating the file
file.write(new_password)              #Adding password to the file
file.close()

print("User succesfuly created!!")
```

This part all runs fine, I just need a way to prevent it from overwriting other users.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: What are the restrictions?

Comment: The computer is from work so I do not have admin privileges so cannot access some features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [open with mode `'x'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open): *"open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists"*.

```
try:
    with open(title, 'x') as file:              
        file.write(new_password)
    print("User successfully created!!")
except FileExistsError:
    print("User already exists!!")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVAxisMwEORadfeDdRrZkLsiVTCkdH6QOgh7fREISeyusf2WNGmSR-U1Z9mXI4FMNbs7MyxzvsVRTsFfLtdO2q_t_eNTrDiEHeiZaOWxP0bD3Adq0vrBtVJtIDiC9UDG_2C-KUqlYILQWM4kobdyghDR53PgGvSgCzAMrXVYwgvU85Du3z1Zwfz5h-JfFMl6yVcHRgLu6hqZ2865EWpCI9hk2WoR41BjFNhPgdVgWbgiClS-DTJuMjfj5EnCFLE081fQo6hf)

Comment: @Kastet6398 They can move the password input into the `with` block. I'm just pointing out the existence of the the `'x'` mode and how to use it. In reality, they likely also want some kind of loop to let the user enter a different name if they entered an existing one, so they need to adapt this code anyway. Same as with yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib` to check if a specific file exists

```
from pathlib import Path

...

title = new_username + '.txt'  # Creating title of the file
is_exists = Path(title).exists() 
if not is_exists:
    with open(title, 'w') as file:
        file.write(new_password)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native python open() function, and then try to open it in read mode. If it doesn't exist, it'll throw an exception and you can catch it, and if it occurred, the file doesn't exist, and everything is OK.

Here's the example code:

```py
new_username = str(input('Please choose a username: '))

title = new_username + '.txt'
try:
    open(title, 'r')
    print("Username already exists. Choose a different one.")
except FileNotFoundError:
    new_password = str(input('Please choose a password: '))
    print("Good Choice!")
    file = open(title, 'w')
    file.write(new_password)
    file.close()
    print("User successfully created!")
```